# Glitchy sound design how-to? Example inside

Tags: post-production, gameaudio, sound-design

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8pNOxynC1Dc&feature=player_detailpage

In the opening sequences there is an odd, glitchy, tremolo kind of effect. The same style of design is used in movies like transformers. What are some ways to go about creating this effect?

Answer (score 5):

one way is to slap a side-chained gate on your source sound, and feed the gate with an irregular (referring to tempo here) sound to control when it opens. if you know what kind of rhythm/a-tempo you want the glitch to have, you can even record yourself tapping with a pair of pens/pencils/drumsticks on a desk or table. this can be the best way to get a useful control on the gate, because the sound you feed to the side-chain key will be easier to use as a control if it is transient in nature.

something else you can try is to use a plug-in like Waves Mondo-Mod and automate the crap out of it.

Answer (score 2):

lots of distortion, lots of compression, and I love this FREE vst plug called dfx skidder.  Really intuitive easy to use way of skittering stuff.  It has some built in distortion that's pretty much useless, but the rest is great.

Answer (score 1):

Also, Izotope Stutter Edit has a lot of these types of effects. They can very easily be mapped to any midi keyboard and "performed" in realtime if you need as well.

They advertise it for music, but it is very useful for SD too.

http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/stutteredit/

Answer (score 1):

I use the air filter gate plug in that comes with pro tools.  Use it as an insert and record to another track.  The one draw back is that you can't automate the pattern or rate parameters so you may need to record several versions, and edit and layer them.

From there you process it using other plug ins (pitch shifters, time expansion/ compression etc.) to make the sound fit for what you need.

I recorded myself de-tuning a string on my guitar, and did one pass with the filter gate plug in.  Check it out here-

http://soundcloud.com/dan2997/air-filter-gate-example

Answer (score 0):

HI, I'm not an expert but found somebody who is into the Glitchy sounds. Have a look if you like:
http://sterilismusic.wordpress.com/2011/10/31/live-cut/#comment-12
It's got nice links to VST's and more...